# How to create a List in a website, when a user clicks on several Divs?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 3 ASPX website. I have created a `View` called `Index` and this `View` is responsible to generate a number of `divs` of different colours, which afterwards are supposed to be used by a user. The user will be presented with a number of clickable areas (divs), which change colours on mouse click. This I can do easily in Javascript. The problem is that down the page I have a submit button, which has to take all the data from previous input fields and also a list of `divs` that were selected by the user and send it further to my C# code.

I have no idea how to create this list and keep it until user sends it further to the C# code, because I suppose it should be Javascript that keeps this list. Otherwise, it should be C# code on the server that gets an integer describing which `div` was selected every time a user clicks on a `div`.

What is the easiest and most elegant way to create this list of `div` indices and send it further to the server, when all data (also other input fields) is combined?

This is my sketch explaining the structure of my website:

[image]

Comment: Is this a new project? If so, why are you choosing to use an old version of MVC? By the way, the standard way of submitting data to the server is via a form, and you can put whatever you want in hidden fields. MVC has model binders that can convert the form values into a C# object (models).

Comment: It's sort of new, but yeah, I plan to switch to MVC 4 soon. Just need to solve this riddle. I am using now MVC 3, because my old website was based on it and I am updating it. Can you elaborate on how to use hidden fields and MVC model binders?

Comment: @mason and is this an elegant way to do this? Or are there any other ways that are not so 'dirty'?

Comment: You can search the web about HTML hidden fields and the model binder in MVC.

Comment: thanks, I already found something. will look into it.